# FileUpload error "resource you are looking for could have been removed"

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I am trying to upload files using fileupload control. When i tried it from my local machine it works fine, But when i deployed it in a server & tried i got below error message.

It seems to be permission related issue, if the file is in same virtual directory, it is getting uploaded. It throws an error when we try to upload file from other server, or C Drive.

how can i overcome this issue, Please guide...

the error message is

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

```
   Requested URL: /SharePoint/ErrorPage.aspx
```

Comment: I think there is a path problem.. use server.map path instead of hard coded values

Comment: Where it should be added?

Comment: Where you are uploading the file.. Make sure you have added Server.MapPath.. Are you using it aleady.. when exactly the error is occurring ?

Comment: I am uploading file from the Webapplication deployed on the server. I am justing using the URL to access the application, which will upload files from my local machine directory. After browsing the file from my local machine & clicking on upload button, i am getting that error.

Comment: What do you mean Server.MapPath?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have written in Upload button ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38866/discussion-between-pradip-and-saravanakumarr)

Answer (score 0):

Once the application is deployed in the Server, the file upload control expects the file to be present in the Local machine (Application hosted server), where actually file doesn't exist.

So we have to move the file from local machine into server, then try uploading it.
It works perfect.

PFB, example.

```
            string tempFileForStorage = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetFileName(FileName));
            fileUploadSharePoint.SaveAs(tempFileForStorage);

            if (null != fileUploadSharePoint.PostedFile)
            {
                webclient.UploadFile(URL, "PUT", tempFileForStorage);
                webclient.Dispose();
                Response.Write("<h1>Success</h1>");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<h1>File not found</h1>");
            }
```